# Extending partition of a hard disk in windows 7 boot camp (Mac)

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, boot-camp

everyone. I would like to ask if there is anyway to extend the partition I gave for setting up window 7, I initially gave 60 GB to window, and now they ate up a lot of bytes and I probably need more bytes , How can I get it without reinstalling everything? or deleting everything ? Thanks
Please suggest some methods which is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you right click on your computer you can Manage your PC. When you click on Manage a window will open. Click on Disk Management, after you see all your hard drive partitions, click on the one that contains your windows install. If you right click on the partition you will see 2 options Shrink Volume and Extend Volume. If you have a 1GB hard drive with 2 partitions, 1 250GB, second 750GB, and windows 7 installed on the first (250GB) partition, The EXTEND option will NOT be available. You will first need to SHRINK the second partition by 250GB, and then Extend the main partition. 
WARNING! If you have data on the second partition, you will loose it all. So backup everything before shrinking...

Good luck